# Inject contact into Journey Builder using AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am currently investigating the quickest way to get a contact into a Journey. I am aware of all the standard methods of doing so, but I was wondering if any of you knew of a way to do it using AMPscript?

If the requirement is immediate injection - either based on email send or landing page, ampscript would be the only way to do so? or?

Comment: There is no AMPscript function fire an Event. The only thing I can think of is to create an Automation with a single Fire Event Activity, then in your email or landing page, use the InsertData/InsertDE AMPscript functions to add the Contact to your Event Source DE and use the InvokePerform function to start the Automation. However, this isn't a very sensible way to inject Contacts into a Journey if you are sending thousands of emails. I'm happy to provide an example of how to achieve this using AMPscript, if this solution meets your use case. If it doesn't perhaps you can expand further.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Eliot! At the moment, i'm trying to clarify ways to achieve this. I know that with classic smart capture, SF Record Creation or update - we can achieve close to immediate injection. 

But it seems that marketing cloud, apart from the above, relies on scheduled automations causing a delay. I suppose you would use invokeperform via the api as well? to inject a contact and fire immediately?

A hypothetical use case could be a subscriber visits a pricing page, and we want to immediately inject said person into a journey?

Comment: The AMPscript API functions only work with the SOAP API methods. You could use the REST API [events method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) in conjunction with an AMPscript [HTTPPost](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httppost/) function, but you would also need to create and manage your OAuth access token which could be cumbersome. However, if you let me know how many times an hour you predict a Contact would be entering a journey then I can craft an answer for you.

Comment: Also, if you are already using Sales Cloud, you could use [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) or [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) to upsert a record then use a Salesforce Data Event in your Journey to inject the Contact. However, it's not a good idea to do this unless you actually want to create a record in Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. I don't have a particular issue, yet, but will be in positions in the near future where I'll be asked about this - compared to other vendors, who can create triggers in their own web analytics layer, and push this over - not just as a triggered email, but as injections into a flow - and trying to figure out the best way to achieve this. It seems that it has to be based on either the REST api or and update to a field in salesforce, based on either an integration towards salesforce or executed via a triggered send. hmm :)